# Find the value of a text field in a onClick function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
function myFunction(id,value){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/inc/scripts/post.php",
        data: { "did": id, "value": value },
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data.message);
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("ERROR");
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<input name="value_'.$objet['did'].'" class="form-control" placeholder="Quantité" value="" required="" type="text">
<div class="bouton-menu" onClick="myFunction('.$objet['did'].',value of the field text)">OK</div>
```

How can I find the value in the text and put it in `myFunction() (onClick)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove second parameter in myFunction and use this code:

```
function myFunction(id){
var value = $(input['name=value_' + id]).val()
$.ajax(
  {
   type:"POST",
   url:"/inc/scripts/post.php",
   data:{"did":id,"value":value},
   dataType:"JSON",
    success: function(data) {
    alert(data.message);
    },
        error:function(){
            alert("ERROR");

        }
  }
 );
}
```

Comment: Thank you I could find the solution put var value = $ ("#value_" + id) .val ();

Answer (score 1):

Add an id to your input field and you can get it value in your function as follow

```
data:{"did":id,"value":$('#ID_OF_TEXT_FIELD').val()},
```

Comment: The problem is that there are several id I use a php loop.

Comment: Try 
`<div class="bouton-menu" onClick="myFunction('.$objet['did'].',$([name='value_'.$objet['did'].']).val())">OK</div>`

Comment: Does not work (or I did wrong), but I found the solution to Dusan. Thank you guys :)

Comment: Try to use jQuery wildcard selector

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, try attaching your events using jQuery. It's a better practice and leaves your HTML looking cleaner:

```
<input name="value_'.$objet['did'].'" class="form-control" placeholder="Quantité" value="" required="" type="text">
<div class="bouton-menu" data-id="'.$objet['did'].'">OK</div>
```

Then you can do the following in jQuery:

```
$('.bouton-menu').click(function() {
    var value = ;
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "/inc/scripts/post.php",
        data: { 
            "did": $(this).data('id'), 
            "value": $('.form-control').val() 
        },
        dataType:"JSON",
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data.message);
        },
        error:function(){
            alert("ERROR");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

give a id to the input 
for example

```
<input type="text" id="myval"/>
```

instead of on click in html call a function in javascript , inside that before ajax

```
var myvalue = $("#myval").val();
```